# Parsing mixed structured and unstructured data

Tags: python, csv, parsing

A lot of spectroscopic data, simulation output files... in our field comes as mix of structured and unstructured data.

An example is the following file, where the three dots are 
standing for other lines in between.

```
...
...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DGA/MPI-2 Parallel Environment:    4 Molcas's processes are running on   1 node(s) x  4 cores each 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
...
      Mulliken charges per centre and basis function type
      ---------------------------------------------------

             O1      C2      CR3     O4      CR5     O6      O7      C8      O9      O10     O11     C12
      1s     1.9991  1.9984  2.0000  1.9992  2.0000  1.9986  1.9986  1.9983  1.9993  1.9987  1.9986  1.9983
      2s     1.7994  1.0697  2.0000  1.8080  2.0000  1.8648  1.8692  1.0827  1.7580  1.8781  1.8582  1.0834
      2px    1.9368  0.7559  2.0000  1.9364  2.0000  1.6998  1.6786  0.7228  1.9829  1.6891  1.7016  0.7757
      2pz    1.4406  0.6506  2.0000  1.4297  2.0000  1.7096  1.6791  0.6758  1.4469  1.6580  1.7045  0.6490
      2py    1.7790  0.5652  2.0000  1.7909  2.0000  1.5122  1.5263  0.5719  1.5781  1.4733  1.5474  0.5655
      3s    -0.0040  0.0107  1.9934 -0.0041  1.9932 -0.0093 -0.0095  0.0091 -0.0064 -0.0072 -0.0099  0.0106
      3px   -0.0032  0.0205  1.9939 -0.0031  1.9942 -0.0111 -0.0139  0.0189 -0.0015 -0.0107 -0.0145  0.0460
      3pz   -0.0122 -0.0118  1.9936 -0.0114  1.9936 -0.0077 -0.0073 -0.0072 -0.0102 -0.0070 -0.0076 -0.0035
      3py   -0.0021  0.1446  1.9912  0.0005  1.9919 -0.0113 -0.0112  0.1360 -0.0070 -0.0087 -0.0125  0.1386
      4s     0.0000  0.0000  0.1958  0.0000  0.1914  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
      3d2+   0.0000  0.0000  0.6978  0.0000  0.6939  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
      3d1+   0.0000  0.0000  0.4320  0.0000  0.4423  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
```

Usually some parts have to be parsed manually, but if you reach the beginning of the example table, all the information about the size of the table is at hand and it would be great to use finished table readers. The problem is, all of the typical readers I know of don't allow to give byte offsets.  (csv module, pandas, numpy)

This leads to two possible workarounds:

1. Line offsets are given. This means that the called csv reader will read the whole file from the beginning and count the newline characters on its own. I know that they are usually implemented in C and still very fast, but I think it is ugly, to throw away the available information.
2. A string is created and passed as `StringIO` object into the readers.

Like the following example code:

```
import io
with open('test.log') as f:
    title = 'Mulliken charges per centre and basis function type'
    for line in f: 
        if title == line.strip():
            break
    f.readline()

    known_from_previous_parsing = 18
    mull_charges = ''.join([f.readline() for j in range(known_from_previous_parsing)])
    mull_charges = io.StringIO(mull_charges)
    mull_charges = pd.read_csv(mull_charges, delim_whitespace=True)
```

The problem with the second approach is, that it writes the table en bloc into memory, throwing all the advantages of automatic buffering... away.
(And before you ask, this is not premature optimisation, the tables may become so big, that reading them en bloc leads to swapping.)

So my question is: Are there csv parsing tools in python that allow to specify a byte offset. Or to ask more general, am I on the right track with my approach and how should I tackle such a mix of structured and unstructured data?

Comment: You can just pass `f` to `read_csv` with `nrows=known_from_previous_parsing`, no need to read it into memory first.

Comment: What is your Target, `pandas` or `csv` or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't tell about panda, but with the `csv` module you can advance the file pointer (using `readline()` or `next()`) until you're just before the first line of tabular data, then proceed as with any ordinary csv file (assuming you don't have more unstructured text AFTER the tabular data that is):

offset.dat

```
This is useles
This is useles
This is useles

Data:
AAA,42
BBB,56
CCC,8878
```

Python shell:

```
>>> import csv
>>> f = open("offset.dat")
>>> line = f.next()
>>> while not line.startswith("Data:"):
...     line = f.next()
... 
>>> line
'Data:\n'
>>> r = csv.reader(f)
>>> r.next()
['AAA', '42']
>>> r.next()
['BBB', '56']
>>> r.next()
['CCC', '8878']
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is clever enough to deal with this, assuming that this content is at the end of the file. Use the `skiprows` parameters.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('temp.txt', sep='\s+',skiprows=10)
>>> df
          O1      C2     CR3      O4     CR5      O6      O7      C8      O9  \
1s    1.9991  1.9984  2.0000  1.9992  2.0000  1.9986  1.9986  1.9983  1.9993   
2s    1.7994  1.0697  2.0000  1.8080  2.0000  1.8648  1.8692  1.0827  1.7580   
2px   1.9368  0.7559  2.0000  1.9364  2.0000  1.6998  1.6786  0.7228  1.9829   
2pz   1.4406  0.6506  2.0000  1.4297  2.0000  1.7096  1.6791  0.6758  1.4469   
2py   1.7790  0.5652  2.0000  1.7909  2.0000  1.5122  1.5263  0.5719  1.5781   
3s   -0.0040  0.0107  1.9934 -0.0041  1.9932 -0.0093 -0.0095  0.0091 -0.0064   
3px  -0.0032  0.0205  1.9939 -0.0031  1.9942 -0.0111 -0.0139  0.0189 -0.0015   
3pz  -0.0122 -0.0118  1.9936 -0.0114  1.9936 -0.0077 -0.0073 -0.0072 -0.0102   
3py  -0.0021  0.1446  1.9912  0.0005  1.9919 -0.0113 -0.0112  0.1360 -0.0070   
4s    0.0000  0.0000  0.1958  0.0000  0.1914  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   
3d2+  0.0000  0.0000  0.6978  0.0000  0.6939  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   
3d1+  0.0000  0.0000  0.4320  0.0000  0.4423  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   

         O10     O11     C12  
1s    1.9987  1.9986  1.9983  
2s    1.8781  1.8582  1.0834  
2px   1.6891  1.7016  0.7757  
2pz   1.6580  1.7045  0.6490  
2py   1.4733  1.5474  0.5655  
3s   -0.0072 -0.0099  0.0106  
3px  -0.0107 -0.0145  0.0460  
3pz  -0.0070 -0.0076 -0.0035  
3py  -0.0087 -0.0125  0.1386  
4s    0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  
3d2+  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  
3d1+  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
```

If it isn't, and you know or can calculate the number of lines in the table, then you can still use this sort of script with the `rows` parameter.

Once you've read the table with pandas you can send it to a csv, to a sql db, to excel, etc.